# When did MySQL start supporting XML functions?

Tags: mysql, xml, database, function

How long have the MySQL XML functions like [ExtractValue()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xml-functions.html) and [UpdateXML()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xml-functions.html) been supported?

*A rough version number will do.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5.1.5.

[MySql 5.1 documentation Section 11.11 XML Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html)

> Beginning with MySQL 5.1.5, two functions providing basic XPath 1.0 (XML Path Language, version 1.0) capabilities are available. Some basic information about XPath syntax and usage is provided later in this section; however, an in-depth discussion...

Comment: 1+ Short, concise, accurate, and real easy to [Google](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html) (found it by searching `xml functions mysql`, first hit).